# How can I insert spaces between words given a list of lists of coded letters?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, spacing

Figured out the "o" thing. It was taking the second element in the list rather than the second list within the list. But now I am back to spacing issues...

```
MORSE = {'.-':    'a', '-...':  'b', '-.-.':  'c',
         '-..':   'd', '.':     'e', '..-.':  'f',
         '--.':   'g', '....':  'h', '..':    'i',
         '.---':  'j', '-.-':   'k', '.-..':  'l',
         '--':    'm', '-.':    'n', '---':   'o',
         '.--.':  'p', '--.-':  'q', '.-.':   'r',
         '...':   's', '-':     't', '..-':   'u',
         '...-':  'v', '.--':   'w', '-..-':  'x',
         '-.--':  'y', '--..':  'z', '-----': '0',
         '.----': '1', '..---': '2', '...--': '3',
         '....-': '4', '.....': '5', '-....': '6',
         '--...': '7', '---..': '8', '----.': '9'
        }

def morse_decoder(code):
    words = code.split("   ")
    words2d = []
    for i in words:
        words = i.split()
        words2d.append(words)
    array = []
    for j in range(len(words2d)):
        for k in range(len(words2d[j])):
            array.append(MORSE[words2d[j][k]])
        array.append(" ")
    string = "".join(array)
    return string.capitalize()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Example:")
    print(morse_decoder('... --- ...   ...'))
    print(morse_decoder("... --- -- .   - . -..- -"))

    #These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing
    assert morse_decoder("... --- -- .   - . -..- -") == "Some text"
    assert morse_decoder("..--- ----- .---- ---..") == "2018"
    assert morse_decoder(".. -   .-- .- ...   .-   --. --- --- -..   -.. .- -.--") == "It was a good day"
    print("Coding complete? Click 'Check' to earn cool rewards!")
```

You will notice that my output is "Some text " for input "... --- -- .   - . -..- -" rather than "Some text" (without the space at the end). It appears that the solution to my first problem has created a new one. Getting close... Any guidance appreciated. Thanks.

---

So my original problem of getting the spacing right is resolved. But upon further testing, I am not getting the results I want. I said I wanted "Sos o", and that's what is now printing. But what I actually want is "Sos s" for that input.

The problem appears to lie in my definition of the words2d list. What I am trying to accomplish there is to have the morse code for each word contained in its own list. But for some reason that I would really like to understand it creates the first word list properly, but then the second word is the morse code for "o." Stefan has given me some alternative code below that performs the basic task of the function (translating morsecode to english), but I would still like to know what was wrong with my code.

---

I am working on creating a function to decode morse code messages and I am running into difficulties in achieving proper spacing in the final string. Basically, I want there to be a space between each word. And I can only manage to achieve no spacing at all (as in the code below) or spaces between every single letter, which is also not desirable. I purposefully organized the words2d list in my code below so that each (coded) word is in its own list, and I think I'm probably on the right track, but not sure where to go from there.

```
MORSE = {'.-':    'a', '-...':  'b', '-.-.':  'c',
         '-..':   'd', '.':     'e', '..-.':  'f',
         '--.':   'g', '....':  'h', '..':    'i',
         '.---':  'j', '-.-':   'k', '.-..':  'l',
         '--':    'm', '-.':    'n', '---':   'o',
         '.--.':  'p', '--.-':  'q', '.-.':   'r',
         '...':   's', '-':     't', '..-':   'u',
         '...-':  'v', '.--':   'w', '-..-':  'x',
         '-.--':  'y', '--..':  'z', '-----': '0',
         '.----': '1', '..---': '2', '...--': '3',
         '....-': '4', '.....': '5', '-....': '6',
         '--...': '7', '---..': '8', '----.': '9'
        }

def morse_decoder(code):
    words = code.split("   ")
    words2d = []
    for i in range(len(words)):
        words = words[i].split()
        words2d.append(words)
    array = []
    for j in range(len(words2d)):
        for k in range(len(words2d[j])):
            array.append(MORSE[words2d[j][k]])
        array.append(" ") #This is the line I was missing initially
    string = "".join(array)
    return string.capitalize()

print(morse_decoder('... --- ...   ...')) #should print "Sos s"
```

Comment: hey Aaron. Welcome to Stack Overflow. can you please provide us with the output you are getting?

Comment: I am getting the following output: Soso

Answer (score 1):

Just append another whitespace in array:

```
def morse_decoder(code):
    words = code.split("   ")
    words2d = []
    for i in range(len(words)):
        words = words[i].split()
        words2d.append(words)
    array = []
    for j in range(len(words2d)):
        for k in range(len(words2d[j])):
            array.append(MORSE[words2d[j][k]])
        array.append(" ")    ### NEW STATEMENT
    string = "".join(array)
    return string.capitalize()

print(morse_decoder('... --- ...   ...'))
Sos o
```

Comment: rip I got sniped

Comment: Well, that did what I wanted it to do. So thank you for that. But apparently the problems in my code run deeper than I realized: print(morse_decoder("... --- -- .   - . -..- -")) for example gives me the string "Someo" rather than "Some text." I'm not sure where the problem lies.

Comment: I would recommend posting it as a separate question because its hard to see your input and output here. Post a new question with inputs and outputs (expected and actual).

Comment: I also just realized that I did not want "Sos o". I want "Sos s". I have no idea why the second list in my words2d list is coming out "---" rather than "..." in the case of input "... --- ...   ..." I is doing the same for other inputs as well.

Comment: Will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```py
morse_dict = {'.-':    'a', '-...':  'b', '-.-.':  'c',
         '-..':   'd', '.':     'e', '..-.':  'f',
         '--.':   'g', '....':  'h', '..':    'i',
         '.---':  'j', '-.-':   'k', '.-..':  'l',
         '--':    'm', '-.':    'n', '---':   'o',
         '.--.':  'p', '--.-':  'q', '.-.':   'r',
         '...':   's', '-':     't', '..-':   'u',
         '...-':  'v', '.--':   'w', '-..-':  'x',
         '-.--':  'y', '--..':  'z', '-----': '0',
         '.----': '1', '..---': '2', '...--': '3',
         '....-': '4', '.....': '5', '-....': '6',
         '--...': '7', '---..': '8', '----.': '9'
        }

def morse_decoder(code):
    code = code.strip()
    """#-remove quotes to uncomment
    #-this part of codes removes characters that arent needed
    code = list(code)
    indexes_to_remove = []
    for i in range(len(code)):
        if code[i] != "." and code[i] != "-" and code[i] != " ":
            indexes_to_remove.append(i)
    for i in range(len(indexes_to_remove)):
        del code[int(indexes_to_remove[i] - i)] 
    code = "".join(code)
    #-remove quotes to uncomment"""
    translated_words_list = []
    words = code.split("   ")
    for i in range(len(words)):
        word = str(words[i]).split(" ")
        for j in range(len(word)):
            translated_words_list.append(morse_dict.get(str(word[j])))
        translated_words_list.append(" ")
    str_translated_words = "".join(translated_words_list)
    return(str_translated_words.capitalize())#edit: forgot to add .capitalize()

print(morse_decoder('... --- ...   ...')) # print "Sos s"
```

Comment: I reposted as a new question as my original question didn't adequately address all of the problems with my code. Thanks.  -- Well, I thought I did. It appears it did not post. I will have to rewrite it and try again

Comment: could you link me to that question? tnx

Comment: Apparently I have to wait 90 minutes before asking another question. I will provide a link upon posting later today.

Comment: you could tell me other problems here, so you don't have to post a new question?

Comment: So essentially my code is printing the first decoded word followed by "o" for the second word irrespective of input. The problem appears to lie in the step where I define words2d within the function. When input is '... --- ... ...' I want [..., ---, ...] [...] for words2d. But that is not what I am getting it appears.

Comment: did you check out my version? it was printing out "s". If thats the case, i think you could mark it as the answer and end this thread :)

Comment: I haven't had the chance to run your version yet. But I'm still unclear on what is going wrong in my code. Having a code that works is great. But I really want to know what I'm doing wrong and the steps to fix it so that I can learn from my failure.

Comment: you should just used "dict.get('...")" for example to get value next to it, "s" in this case. If you dont understand my code, i dont blame you, cus i dont either ha ha:/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221027/discussion-between-stefan-j-and-aaron-fehir).

Comment: Instead of posting a new question when it is really the same question and you are adding more information or clarification, please just edit your original question instead. You can edit a question as many times as you want, just use the 'edit' link below the question.

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you Michael for the tip. -- Stefan, I've checked your code, and yes, it does seem to work properly. I am still most interested in understanding what I am doing though, and particularly, where that "o" is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Got it... just had to add "string = string[:-1]" in order to remove the final space. I added the line right before the return line in the function. Thank you everyone for the assistance.